# Pyinstaller shows "failed to execute script" but the programs runs fine

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

My program named "gui.py" does not use PyQt5. When I try to convert it to .exe file it shows the error

```
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

If I try again after installing PyQt5, it convert into .exe file, but shows the error

```
Failed to execute script gui.py
```

Why is PyQt5 necessary for pyinstaller?
Gui.py itself run fine via command line, but don't run via double clicking gui.exe file.

Comment: Try to use the console mode (remove `-w` or `noconsole` flags) and check if you get any errors.

Comment: Without the "-w", the error "Failed to execute script gui.py" is shown in the terminal.